# How to share arguments/variables between executable python script and python script?

Tags: python, parsing, variables, terminal, arguments

I have a script (test.py) that I run as a command from the terminal, which calls another script (main.py). I want to store the arguments entered by the user as variables, and then pass them onto the second script.

E.g. when I run 'test -t foo' I want to save 'foo' as 'test=foo', and then when I call 'os.system("python main.py")' at the end of test.py I want main.py to print 'foo'.

This is what I have so far:

**test.py**

```
import os, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", action="store", help="Store argument as variable")
args = parser.parse_args()

#I'm not sure how to save the argument as a variable

os.system("python main.py") #I need to keep this line - please see the comments below
```

**terminal commands**

```
chmod +x test.py
mv test.py test

mkdir -p ~/bin
cp test ~/bin
echo 'export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/bin"' >> .profile
```

**main.py**

```
from __main__ import * #this does not work

if args.test:
    print(#variable)
```

Comment: **Why** exactly do you want to use `os.system` to launch one Python script from another? Why not just `import` something and call a function etc., the way that code in multiple Python files *normally* interacts?

Comment: When you try to do things this way, `python main.py` starts a **completely new program** that has **nothing to do with** the Python process that is running `test.py`.

Comment: The example is a bit simplified - I'm not actually running os.system("python main.py"), but os.system("pymol -cqQ main.py"), main.py executes pymol log files. I'm making a command line tool for pymol. It's important we keep this line, otherwise my code does not work

Comment: What is `pymol`? Did you try reading its documentation, to see if it has any advice, on how to provide information to the script? If you were directly running `pymol -cqQ main.py` from the command line yourself, how would you intend for `main.py` to know about the value? If the goal is to work around something like "pymol doesn't forward any command-line arguments to my script" then you are going to need a fundamentally different approach.

Comment: When I try to look up `pymol`, I can't find anything about it supporting any command-line flags at all. It looks like you're intended to use it as a program, by providing Python-like commands to its own interpreter command line... ? At any rate, it seems like you should instead try asking that community for tech support. There are [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pymol) existing questions tagged `[pymol]`, but.

Comment: It's not the problem that pymol doesn't forward command line arguments, pymol is just a software for modelling proteins and it uses both python and pymol commands. pymol -cqQ main.py works perfectly fine because I used to have the user input the variables using variable=input("Input variable "). Now I want to polish the program so you don't have to input variables when prompted, but instead just specify them as arguments at the start.

Comment: The problem is with test.py being an executable file. I have also tried storing the variables in a completely separate file variables.py and importing them into main.py which works, but the problem is I want arguments, so the variables have to be stored in test.py - I might be wrong about this though. Please don't get hung up on the pymol stuff

Comment: If you want `main.py` to have **command-line** arguments, then pass them **on the command line** when starting `main.py` - and it will have to do its own parsing.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is helpful for anyone, I have found a way around the problem:

**test.py**

```
import os, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", action="store", type=str, default="None", help="Store argument as variable")
args = parser.parse_args()

with open ("variables.py", 'w') as variables:
    variables.writelines(args.test)

os.system("python main.py")
```

**terminal commands**

```
chmod +x test.py
mv test.py test

mkdir -p ~/bin
cp test ~/bin
echo 'export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/bin"' >> .profile
```

**main.py**

```
with open ("variables.py", 'r') as variables:
    test = variables.read()
print(test)
```

It's probably not very pythonic but it does the trick.